# How to encode recursive types with constraint for a typesafe avro library

Tags: scala, avro

Since I'm kinda really stumped right now with this issue I thought I'd ask here.

So here's the problem. I'm currently trying to write a Library to represent Avro Schemas in a typesafe manner that should then later allow to structurally query a given runtime value of a schema. E.g. Does my schema contain a field of a given name within a certain path? Is the schema flat (contains no nestable types except at top level)? etc.
You can find the complete specification of Avro schemas here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html

Now I have some troubles deciding on a representation of the schema within my code. Right now I'm using an ADT like this because it makes decoding the AvroSchema (which is JSON) really easy with Circe so you can somewhat ignore things like the Refined Types for this issue.
https://gist.github.com/GrafBlutwurst/681e365ecbb0ecad2acf4044142503a9 Please note that this is not the exact implementation. I have one that is able to decode schemas correctly but is a pain to query afterwards.
Anyhow I was wondering:

1) Does anyone have a good Idea how to encode the Typerestriction on AVRO Union. Avro Unions cannot contain other Unions directly, but can for example contain Records which then again can contain Unions. So union -> union is not allowed but union -> record -> union is ok.

2) would using fixpoint recursion in form of Fix, Free and CoFree make the querying later easier? I'm somewhat on the fence since I have no experience using these yet.

Thanks!

PS: Here's some more elaboration on why Refined is in there. In the end I want to enable some very specific uses eg this pseudocode (I'm not quite sure if it is at all possible yet?:

```
refine[Schema Refined IsFlat](schema) //because it's flat I know it can only be a Recordtype with Fields of Primitives or Optionals (encoded as Union [null, primitive])
    .folder { //wonky name
        case AvroInt(k, i) => k + " -> " + i.toString
        case AvroString(k, s) => k + " -> " + s
        //etc...
     } // should result in a function List[Vector[Byte]] => Either[Error,List[String]]
```

Basically given a schema and assuming it satisfies the IsFlat constraint, provide a function that decodes records and convert them into string lists.

Comment: *Does anyone have a good Idea how to encode the Type restriction on AVRO Union*? Can you give a [MCVE] of what you mean by "encode the type restriction"? You want this to be a compile time constraint although the types are run time generated? Perhaps I have a misunderstanding.

Comment: well so a Union is allowed to contain every other type EXCEPT a Union itself so one possible way this could look like is:

union -> Record/Field -> Union

Currently my complex types form an ADT but I'm not sure how to restrict the Type of the Unionmembers in such a way that a Union can't contain itself directly.

Comment: Is this schema you're creating a compile time construct? Or do you just interpret it at runtime and throw if it's wrong?

Comment: Sadly I can't really give a minimal falsifiable example because I'^m not hunting an error per se. I'm more looking for design advice. But no the schema is indeed read and created at runtime and I could just throw an error. However I want the restriction to be expressed at a type level for multiple reasons. 1) cleaness 2) the usecase of this all is to refine your general schema to a very specific subset of possible schemata (e.g top level record that only contains int fields) so then you can offer very specific operations on that subset (e.g convert to a Ma[Striung,Int])